# Bash regex: get value in conf file preceded by string with dot

Tags: bash, sed, grep, echo

I have to get my db credentials from this configuration file:

```
# Database settings

Aisse.LocalHost=localhost
Aisse.LocalDataBase=mydb
Aisse.LocalPort=5432
Aisse.LocalUser=myuser
Aisse.LocalPasswd=mypwd

# My other app settings

Aisse.NumDir=../../data/Num
Aisse.NumMobil=3000

# Log settings
#Aisse.Trace_AppliTpv=blabla1.tra
#Aisse.Trace_AppliCmp=blabla2.tra
#Aisse.Trace_AppliClt=blabla3.tra
#Aisse.Trace_LocalDataBase=blabla4.tra
```

In particular, I want to get the value `mydb` from line

```
Aisse.LocalDataBase=mydb
```

So far, I have developed this

```
mydbname=$(echo "$my_conf_file.conf" | grep "LocalDataBase=" | sed "s/LocalDataBase=//g" )
```

that returns

```
mydb #Aisse.Trace_blabla4.tra
```

that would be ok if it did not return also the comment string.

Then I have also tryed

```
mydbname=$(echo "$my_conf_file.conf" | grep "Aisse.LocalDataBase=" | sed "s/LocalDataBase=//g" )
```

that retruns void string.

How can I get only the value that is preceded by the string `"Aisse.LocalDataBase="` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're being incomplete:
You mention you want the line, containing "LocalDataBase", but you don't want the line in comment, let's start with that:

A line which contains "LocalDataBase":

```
grep "LocalDataBase" conf.conf.txt
```

A line which contains "LocalDataBase" but who does not start with a hash:

```
grep "LocalDataBase" conf.conf.txt | grep -v "^ *#"
```

??? `grep -v "^ *#"`

That means: don't show (`-v`) the lines, containing:

- `^` : the start of the line
- `*` : a possible list of space characters
- `#`  : a hash character

Once you have your line, you need to work with it:
You only need the part behind the equality sign, so let's use that sign as a delimiter and show the second column:

```
cut -d '=' -f 2
```

All together:

```
grep "LocalDataBase" conf.conf.txt | grep -v "^ *#" | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Are we there yet?
No, because it's possible that somebody has put some comment behind your entry, something like:

```
LocalDataBase=mydb #some information
```

In order to prevent that, you need to cut that comment too, which you can do in a similar way as before: this time you use the hash character as a delimiter and you show the first column:

```
grep "LocalDataBase" conf.conf.txt | grep -v "^ *#" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d '#' -f 1
```

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ mydbname=$(sed -n 's/Aisse\.LocalDataBase=//p' input_file)
$ echo $mydbname
mydb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
mydbname=$(sed -n 's/^Aisse\.LocalDataBase=\(.*\)/\1/p' file)
```

If there can be leading whitespace you can add `[[:blank:]]*` after `^`:

```sh
mydbname=$(sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*Aisse\.LocalDataBase=\(.*\)/\1/p' file)
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/WKla3z):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='# Database settings
 
Aisse.LocalHost=localhost
Aisse.LocalDataBase=mydb
Aisse.LocalPort=5432
Aisse.LocalUser=myuser
Aisse.LocalPasswd=mypwd
 
# My other app settings
 
Aisse.NumDir=../../data/Num
Aisse.NumMobil=3000
 
# Log settings
#Aisse.Trace_AppliTpv=blabla1.tra
#Aisse.Trace_AppliCmp=blabla2.tra
#Aisse.Trace_AppliClt=blabla3.tra
#Aisse.Trace_LocalDataBase=blabla4.tra'

sed -n 's/^Aisse\.LocalDataBase=\(.*\)/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
mydb
```

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppresses default line output in `sed`
- `^[[:blank:]]*Aisse\.LocalDataBase=\(.*\)` - a regex that matches the start of a string (`^`), then zero or more whiespaces (`[[:blank:]]*`), then a `Aisse.LocalDataBase=` string, then captures the rest of the line into Group 1
- `\1` - replaces the whole match with the value of Group 1
- `p` - `p`rints the result of the successful substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
mydbname=$(sed -n 's/^[^#][^=]*LocalDataBase=//p' file)
echo "$mydbname"

mydb
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^#]`: Matches any character other than `#`
- `[^=]*`: Matches 0 or more of any character that is not `=`
- `LocalDataBase=`: Matches text `LocalDataBase=`